# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused: connect

Tags: glassfish, apache-axis

We have a java web application running on Glassfish 2.1. 
We recently changed internet providers which also means out network IP's have changed. 
Our application makes two different web service calls, and both were working fine until this network change. 
We have a web service client manager class which calls a 3rd party web service.

Below is the error I'm receiving.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused: connect 
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430) 
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:203) 
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76) 
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400) 
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225) 
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:435) 
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402) 
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229) 
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

I can access the service on our server using SOAP UI. I can telnet to the IP of the service and if I paste the URL into the server's browser, I get a result.

I have no idea what the problem is or how to fix is. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Has your web application server been restarted since the change?  It may be caching the old I.P. address from startup.

Comment: suggestion 1/2: That is a good example of a bad error message. (very common). You should either: (a) run it in a debugger or (b) edit the apache source code to add those details to the exception message, and find out what host, port, etc. there is, and what the root cause exception was (java.net.ConnectException for example, which is what it looks like but would be wrong to assume it is correct). And then based on the results, either blame the code or the host configuration.

Comment: suggestion 2/2: Check your firewalls and /var/log/messages or /var/log/firewall or equivalent on every host along the path to see where the connection was refused, and check that the service is actually running on the correct IP and port, and that no other machines are using that IP (eg. shut off the interface/unplug the right computer's network and ping the IP to see if there is another machine with the same IP)

Comment: on a Linux/Unix machine, "netstat -aln" (on some machines must run as root) will tell you all listening ports. And ifconfig will tell you your interface IPs. And route -rn will tell you your routes (if you have 2 ips, and the route uses the interface with the other address, you can have such problems.

Comment: Yes, the application server has been restarted many times since changing networks.

Comment: I'm unable to run the application in a debugger. I can only get the application to run in a deployed environment and not from my IDE. I guess I will have to try modifying the Apache Source. I don't have any access to the Firewalls, but have been told by our network guys that there are no blocks. The service is running, as I daid originally, I can successfully make the web service call using SOAP UI on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently we are no longer using a proxy, and the web service connection was still setting the proxy. I removed this setting and it worked!